# Clonar funcion con Switch Case

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero poder clonar la tabla con las funciones `cargar_precio` y `operacion`. Que al escribir un nombre en el input `ITEM` me muestre en el input `VALOR_RE_MO` el precio de dicho `ITEM`, El script clona de forma correcta, y sirven las funciones pero solo para la primera fila o tabla, ya estuve revisando algunas respuestas de la comunidad pero no se asemejan a esta situación, también probé a recorrer los nodos hasta llegar al siguiente `input` pero no funciono.

**SCRIPT para clonar tabla**

```
$(function(){
// Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de 
la tabla
  $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
  $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-
    fija').appendTo("#tabla");
});

// Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
$(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
    $(parent).remove();
    });
});
```

**SCRIPT para mostrar precios**

```
function cargar_precio(valor) {
    var codigo = '';

    switch(valor){
      case '':
          codigo = '';
      break;
      case 'ANCOL':
          codigo = '100';
      break;
      case 'ARTEL':
          codigo = '200';
      break;
  }

  $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val(codigo);

}

function operacion() {

    cargar_precio($('#ITEM').val().toUpperCase());
    var valor = parseInt( $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val()),
    cantidad = parseInt( $('#CANTIDAD').val() );
    if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
        $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val( valor * cantidad );
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tabla">

    <label>Item</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' 
    onkeyup='cargar_precio(this.toUpperCase());' autofocus="autofocus">
    </td>

    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' 
    onkeyup="operacion(this);"
    /></td>

    <label>Valor</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO'/></td>

</table>
```

Comment: ¿Si seleccionas toda la tabla con `$('#tabla')` no te funcionan los eventos en los atributos HTML?

Comment: si selecciono toda la tabla si funciona pero la tabla base, es decir la primer fila que me aparece, si clono esa tabla ahí es cuando no funciona

Comment: Veo bastantes problemas en esto que nos muestras. De entrada, no sé si será una errata o algún problema de ese tipo, pero la fila inicial, con el código proporcionado no funciona como se supone. Podrías añadirlo en un jsFiddle o como fragmento de código ejecutable para confirmar el comportamiento y conocer mejor el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Voy a editar el código para que quede un poco mas claro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que yo entendí, tu quieres poder agregar mas filas que contengan los campos `item`, `cantidad` y `valor` y que funcionen también como la primera fila que ya esta en la tabla, si es así, entonces te comparto lo siguiente:

Un fragmento de código, te comento que no usé `jQuery`.

```js
function cargar_precio(valor, elemento_html){
    var codigo = '';
    
    switch( valor ){
      case '':
        codigo = '';
    break;
    case 'ANCOL':
        codigo = '100';
    break;
    case 'ARTEL':
      codigo = '200';
    break;
   }

    //El parametro 'elemento_html' sirve para referenciar al elemento, este es un elemento HTML creado con la función 'agregar_fila'
  if(elemento_html){
        //Si este paramentro existe, entonces la función 'cargar_precio' fue llamada desde una fila agregada desde la función 'agregar_fila'
    elemento_html.value = codigo;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value = codigo;
   }
}

function operacion(cantidad_, valor_, item_){
    //Los parametros 'cantidad_', 'valor_' e 'item_' sirven para referenciar elementos creados desde 'agregar_fila'
    if(cantidad_ && valor_ && item_){
      cargar_precio( item_.value.toUpperCase(), valor_);

      var valor = parseInt( valor_.value ),
        cantidad = parseInt( cantidad_.value );

    if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
        valor_.value = valor * cantidad;
    }
  }
  else{
      cargar_precio( document.getElementById('ITEM').value.toUpperCase());

    var valor = parseInt( document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value ),
        cantidad = parseInt( document.getElementById('CANTIDAD').value );

    if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
        document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value = valor * cantidad;
    }
  }
}

/*
*En la función agregar_fila, se crea una fila con los campos 'item', 'canntidad' y 'valor' y se insertan en la tabla 'PRODUCTOS'
*/
function agregar_fila(){
    var item = document.createElement('input'),
    cantidad = document.createElement('input'),
    valor = document.createElement('input'),
    fila = document.createElement('tr'),
    celda_item = document.createElement('td'),
    celda_cantidad = document.createElement('td'),
    celda_valor = document.createElement('td');

    item.type = 'text';
   cantidad.type = 'text';
   valor.type = 'text';

  celda_item.appendChild( item );
  celda_cantidad.appendChild( cantidad );
  celda_valor.appendChild( valor );

  fila.appendChild( celda_item );
  fila.appendChild( celda_cantidad );
  fila.appendChild( celda_valor );

    document.getElementById('PRODUCTOS').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild( fila );

    //Se agrgan los evetos 'onkeyup'
  item.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    cargar_precio(this.value.toUpperCase(), valor);
  }, false);

  cantidad.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
      operacion(cantidad, valor, item);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<table id="PRODUCTOS">
   <thead>
    <caption>
     Productos <button onclick="agregar_fila()">Agregar</button>
    </caption>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Item</th>
     <th>Cantidad</th>
     <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' onkeyup='cargar_precio(this.value.toUpperCase());' autofocus="autofocus" O>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' onkeyup="operacion();" />
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO' />
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Siento no darte una explicación mas detallada, si la necesitas escribe en los comentarios.

Espero y te sirva.

**Actualización:**

Respondiendo a tu comentario **@Andersson Viveros Martinez**, te dejo un ejemplo que funciona cloando la fila y no creandola.

```js
//Ya conoces el funcionamiento de las funciones 'cargar_precio' y 'operacion'
function cargar_precio(valor, elemento_html){
    var codigo = '';

    switch( valor ){
        case '':
            codigo = '';
        break;
        case 'ANCOL':
            codigo = '100';
        break;
        case 'ARTEL':
            codigo = '200';
        break;
    }

    if(elemento_html){
        elemento_html.value = codigo;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value = codigo;
    }
}

function operacion(cantidad_, valor_, item_){
    if(cantidad_ && valor_ && item_){
        cargar_precio( item_.value.toUpperCase(), valor_);

        var valor = parseInt( valor_.value ),
            cantidad = parseInt( cantidad_.value );

        if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
            valor_.value = valor * cantidad;
        }
    }
    else{
        cargar_precio( document.getElementById('ITEM').value.toUpperCase());

        var valor = parseInt( document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value ),
            cantidad = parseInt( document.getElementById('CANTIDAD').value );

        if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
            document.getElementById('VALOR_RE_MO').value = valor * cantidad;
        }
    }
}

//El parametro 'lista_de_elementos'
//es una especie de 'array' que no es un 'array' sino un 'NodeList' que contiene los elementos 'input'
function remover_atributos( lista_de_elementos ){
    //Con esta función eliminaremos los atributos como 'id', 'name' y 'onkeyup'
    //para que no interfieran con los demas, recuerda que solo puede
    //haber un elemento con un mismo 'id', es decir, el 'id' debe ser unico 
    //para cada elemento dentro del documento HTML.
    for(var i=0, elemento; elemento=lista_de_elementos[i]; i++){
        if(elemento.tagName == 'INPUT'){
            elemento.removeAttribute('id');
            elemento.removeAttribute('name');
            elemento.removeAttribute('onkeyup');

            //Aprovechamos esta función para limpiar el valor
            elemento.value = '';
        }
    }
}

function agregar_fila(){
    var fila = document.getElementById('FILA_INICIAL').cloneNode(true),
        celdas = fila.getElementsByTagName('td');

    //Removemos los atributos de los elementos 'input' que estan dentro de las celdas (td)
    //El atributo o la propiedad 'childNodes' contiene la 'lista' de tipo 'NodeList'
    remover_atributos( celdas[0].childNodes );
    remover_atributos( celdas[1].childNodes );
    remover_atributos( celdas[2].childNodes );


    //Insertamos el elemento clonado a la tabla
    document.getElementById('PRODUCTOS').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild( fila );
    
    //Le damos el 'foco' a el input donde se capturara el 'item'
    celdas[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();

    //El primer elemento 'td' es el que contiene el elemento 'input'
    //en el cual se capturara el 'item', agregamos el evento 'onkeyup'
    celdas[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        //El elemento "celdas[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]" contiene
        //el input en el que se mostrara el valor
        cargar_precio(this.value.toUpperCase(), celdas[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
    }, false);

    //El segundo elemento 'td' de la fila (tr) contiene el 'input' en el cual
    //se tiene la ingresar la cantidad, en este le agregamos el evento
    //'keyup' para realizar la operacion
    celdas[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        //El 1er argumento que recibe 'operacion' es el input en el
        //que se escribira la cantidad, 'this' es ese 'input' en este contexto
        operacion(this, 

                //El 2do argumento que recibe 'operacion' es el input en el cual
                //se mostrara el valor, ese 'input' es 'celdas[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]'
                //porque la segunda celda contiene ese 'input'
                  celdas[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0],

                //El 3er argumento que recibe 'operacion' es el input en el
                //cual se captura el 'item', el cual es 'celdas[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]'
                //porque la 1er celda contiene ese 'input'
                  celdas[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<table id="PRODUCTOS">
    <thead>
        <caption>
            Productos <button onclick="agregar_fila()">Agregar</button>
        </caption>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Definimos un identificador para poder clonarla usando un identificador -->
        <tr id="FILA_INICIAL">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' onkeyup='cargar_precio(this.value.toUpperCase());' autofocus="autofocus">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' onkeyup="operacion();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola estoy viendo que las funciones y otras características funcionan perfectamente, pero creo que seria mas fácil que se copiara la tabla entera(sin los títulos), para asi no colocar cada `input` y `td`, es esto posible?

Comment: Hola @Andersson Viveros Martinez, te comento, la tabla que está en la respuesta contiene una fila con celdas de cabecera que fungen con "título", con la función "agregar_fila", dichas celdas no se copian, solo se crea una fila (tr) que contienen unas celdas (td) con los "input" de tipo "text", si tú clonas la tabla entera (son los títulos) entonces los atributos como el "id" también se copiarán y las funciones solo se ejecutarían en el último elemento con dicho "id".

Comment: Es posible clonar la tabla o la fila completa? Si, si es posible, también es posible clonarla sin clonar los atributos, si lo haces así, entonces tendrías que "linkear" las funciones a los elementos HTML clonados, también es posible,  trataré de dejarte un ejemplo.

Comment: @Andersson Viveros Martinez, he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: @ ftorres sera que podemos continuar la discusión por algun chat, quiero mostrarte y preguntarte algo

Comment: Claro! Podemos usar [este chat público](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68486/javascript-chat) para hablar sobre Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo esta funcion para clonar lineas de tablas:

```
function AddRemoveRowsAV(){
    var x = 1;
    $('.plusbtnAV').on("click",function() {
        var bindElement =   $(this).attr("bind");
        var x = $("#"+bindElement+" tr").length+1;
        if(x <= 10 ){
            var $clone  = $("#"+bindElement+" tr:last").clone();
            $clone.find('input').each(function(){
                var Cval        =   $(this).val();
                var Cname   =   $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, '');
                var Cid         =   $(this).prop('id').replace(/\d+/g, '');
                $(this).attr('name', Cname + x);
                $(this).prop('id', Cid + x );
                if($.isNumeric(Cval)){
                    $(this).val(x);
                }else{
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
            $clone.find("select").each(function(){
                var Cname   =   $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, '');
                var Cid         =   $(this).prop('id').replace(/\d+/g, '');
                $(this).attr('name', Cname + x);
                $(this).prop('id', Cid + x );
            });
            $("#"+bindElement).append($clone);
        }else{
            alert("Error: no puede Agregar mas Lineas");
        }
    });
    $('.minusbtnAV').on("click",function() {
        var bindElement =   $(this).attr("bind");
        var x = $("#"+bindElement+" tr").length;
        if(x != 1){
            $("#"+bindElement+" tr:last-child").remove();
            x = x - 1;
        }else{
            alert("Error: no puede Quitar todas las Lineas");
        }
    });
}
```

Tendrias que adaptarlo a tus funciones y necesidades; esta funcion usa Jquery y eventos delegados: `$('.plusbtnAV').on("click",function() {`
ya que de lo contrario si agregas contenido al DOM el script no lo detectara.

También hay que destacar que el sistema genera los input con nombres auto incremental basados en un pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta clonar pasandole true a la función.

```
$("#adicional").on('click', function(){
  $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-
    fija').appendTo("#tabla");
});
```